# Possible Visual Studio 2013 Bug Caused by Nuget Package?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2013, nuget

I'm encountering a strange bug in visual studio that seems to be caused by a specific Nuget package named [Ragnar](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ragnar/0.1.0). The package is, by its own description

> "a C++/CLI wrapper for Rasterbar's libtorrent. It aims to provide a (mostly) complete interface to the underlying C++ library."

I've reproduced the bug across multiple machines. So far I've tested Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7 Ultimate and Windows 7 Professional.

#### Steps to reproduce:

- Create a new WPF project
- `PM> install-package ragnar`
- Save all and restart Visual Studio 2013
- Reopen the project from the Visual Studio 2013 start page.

#### Errors:

> System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException
>
> [5448] Designer process terminated unexpectedly!

> The exception unknown software exception (0xe0434352) occurred in the application at location 0x74efc42d

> There is not enough virtual memory available. Please save your work and restart (0).

> The instruction at 0x7740e823 referenced memory at 0x00000024. The memory could not be read.

At this point Visual Studio 2013 becomes unresponsive and needs to be killed via the task manager. Removing the reference created by Nuget stops the issue, so I've confirmed it's Ragnar.dll that's causing the issue.

Any ideas what could be causing this? Is this a Visual Studio bug or just weird behavior caused by a buggy class library?

Comment: Hmm. Might be related to background Intellisense gathering? In any case, this looks like a bug you should report on Connect.

Comment: @Cameron I've submitted a [report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/925810/nuget-package-ragnar-crashes-visual-studio-when-installed-via-the-nuget-package-manager)

Answer (score 0):

If this is a bug in the package itself, please contact the owner of this package and ask them to update the package. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ragnar/0.1.0

Comment: I've already submitted a Microsoft Connect report and created an issue on the project's Github repo. Currently I'm waiting for word back from Microsoft Connect as the project dev was unable to reproduce the bug and wants to see if anything comes of the Connect report.